# Lisp labels function deleted before used

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to use a local function using labels to allow my function to recurse. 
This is the code:

```
(defun  my-replace (e1 e2 L)
  "Perform a deep replace e1 with e2 in L."
  (labels ((my-replace-rec (e1 e2 L)
             "Used for recursion"
             (cond ((endp L) nil)
                   ((equal (car L) e1) (cons e2 (cdr L)))
                   ((listp (car L)) (my-replace-rec e1 e2 (car L)))
                   (t (my-replace-rec e1 e2 (cdr L)))))))
    (my-replace-rec e1 e2 L))
```

When I have slime evaluate the function and try to run it:

```
;   Note: Deleting unused function                                                
;   (LABELS MY-REPLACE-REC)                                                     
; ;                                                                             

; Warning: This function is undefined:                                          
;   MY-REPLACE-REC
```

I tried to fit in as much of the error message as I could, but I'm working with Emacs (which I'm still very new to) and trying to paste out of a small buffer.

Why is this happening? It is defined and used, but it seems it keeps getting deleted (supposedly because it's not used) before it's used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your indentation is off. Here is your code indented correctly:

```
(defun  my-replace (e1 e2 L)
  "Perform a deep replace e1 with e2 in L."
  (labels ((my-replace-rec (e1 e2 L)
              "Used for recursion"
              (cond ((endp L) nil)
                    ((equal (car L) e1) (cons e2 (cdr L)))
                    ((listp (car L)) (my-replace-rec e1 e2 (car L)))
                    (t (my-replace-rec e1 e2 (cdr L))))))
          ;; empty labels body here.. 
          )
  ;; my-replace-rec is a global function expected to be defun-ed later
  (my-replace-rec e1 e2 L))
```

`labels` work just like `let`. You need to use the created objects in the body of `labels` and not after the function has been destroyed.

With let:

```
(let ((a 10))
  ; a exists here
  )
; a doesn't exist anymore
```

With `labels`

```
(labels ((name (arg) arg))
  ; the function exists here
  )
;the function doesn't esist anymore
```

In your code you make `my-replace-rec` then in the body of labels you do *nothing* and after the `my-replace-rec` is destroyed you call it. Common Lisp doesn't have any warning about that because it expects you will define it globally later. It does not compare it with the scope you happened to not use.

By moving the ending parentheses so that the call to `my-replace-rec` is done in the `labels` emacs will ident the code correctly:

```
(defun  my-replace (e1 e2 L)
  "Perform a deep replace e1 with e2 in L."
  (labels ((my-replace-rec (e1 e2 L)
              "Used for recursion"
              (cond ((endp L) nil)
                    ((equal (car L) e1) (cons e2 (cdr L)))
                    ((listp (car L)) (my-replace-rec e1 e2 (car L)))
                    (t (my-replace-rec e1 e2 (cdr L))))))
    (my-replace-rec e1 e2 L)))
```

Now when you look at your code it looks the same as this because you have idented it as if `my-replace-rec` was used in the labels while the editor  and your implementation knows that it wasn't.